# WinAPI PBM_GETRANGE always returns 0 when sent to another process's window

Tags: c++, winapi, sendmessage

I'm trying to get the range and current value from a progress bar of another program but:

```
SendMessage(hWnd,PBM_GETRANGE,false,NULL);
```

always returns 0 even though the high limit is definitely not 0.

Comment: Are you sure `hWnd` is the correct handle of the progress bar?

Comment: Yes the handle is right. I got a Window Info Tool from AutoIt which is based on Spy++ and when i send a WM_GETTEXT message I get ID_PROGRESS_BAR so this also confirms that it is the right one.

Comment: When sending messages across process boundaries, both the sender and receiver must have the same bitness. Also, the receiver must not be elevated beyond the access rights of the sender. You should also consider doing this the right way: [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable I'm not sure I agree with the first sentence. For instance you can use WM_SETTEXT, WM_GETTEXT, WM_CLOSE, WM_COPYDATA and so on across bitness boundaries. But yes, automation API is the right way forward.

Comment: System messages are automatically marshaled.  Anything beyond WM_USER is not, they can't be since the message number is ambiguous.